# hyperplanes equivalent as Affine Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

For what values of $t\in \mathbb R$ hyperplanes described with following equations: $$\Pi_1: 5x^2_1+3x^2_2+6x_1 x_2+4x_1 x_3+4x_1+4x_3+8=0
\\ \Pi_2:-x_1^2+x_2^2+(t+2)x^2_3-4x_2+2=0$$
are affinely equivalent.

So I have no intuition other than the geometrical one where I imagine this to planes to be parallel in 4 dimensional space. So i think the free of variable terms in this equation really doesn't matter and we can analyze
$$\Pi'_1: 5x^2_1+3x^2_2+6x_1 x_2+4x_1 x_3+4x_1+4x_3=0
\\ \Pi'_2:-x_1^2+x_2^2+(t-2)x^2_3-4x_2=0$$
Second thing I thought about that I need these equation to  look "the same" with the only difference being the shift in the variables which is geometrically just translation by a vector and would keep planes "parallel". Anyway this is not doable since I will never get $5x_1^2$ term in  $\Pi'_2$ and hence those planes are never affine.

Is my reasoning all right? Could some one give me a glimpse how it should look like algebraically and best using this parallel thing instead of using the definition in terms of action.
Thanks.

Comment: @amd thanks it was a typo

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by these two quadric surfaces (not hyperplanes) being affine. If it means that one can be obtained from the other via an affine transformation, then your idea of examining when they look “the same” is a good one, but you reach the wrong conclusion. There’s more to it than simple translations.

Answer (score 0):

Affine transformations are not just translations, they are combinations of translations and linear transformations i.e. applications $f$ of the form $f : x \mapsto Ax + b$ where $A \in \mathrm{M}_3(\mathbb{R})$ ($\mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ for invertible ones) and $b \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Geometrically, it means that you can obtain $\Pi_{2,t}$ by zooming in or out in all three direction, rotation and translating $\Pi_1$. To determine for which $t$, such an $f$ exists, there are a few tricks to make the computations easier but in the end, you will have to go into some calculus.

Let us call $P$ the polynomial that defines $\Pi_1$ and $Q_t$ the one that defined $\Pi_{2,t}$.

Assume that there exists an invertible linear transformation $f : x \mapsto Ax + b$ which induces a diffeomorphism from $\Pi_1$ to $\Pi_{2,t}$ for a given $t \in \mathbb{R}$. In implies that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $P(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow Q_t(f(x)) = 0$. Now, let us complexify everything, so we can use algebraic geometry arguments.

**Lemma :** If $R \in \mathbb{R}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ is such that there exists at least a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $R(x_0) = 0$ and $\nabla R(x_0) \neq 0$, then $V_\mathbb{C}(R) = \overline{V_\mathbb{R}(R)}$ where $V_\mathbb{R}(R) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n|R(x) = 0\}$, $V_\mathbb{C}(R) = \{x \in \mathbb{C}^n|R(x) = 0\}$ and $\overline{\cdot}$ is the Zariski closure in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Indeed, $V_\mathbb{C}(R)$ is Zariski closed and it contains $V_\mathbb{R}(R)$ hence $\overline{V_\mathbb{R}(R)} \subset V_\mathbb{C}(R)$. Reciprocally, if $S$ is a complex polynomial such that $V_\mathbb{R}(R) \subset V_\mathbb{C}(S)$, then at $x_0$, the ring $\mathcal{O}_{x_0}(V_\mathbb{C}(R))$ is local with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} = R\mathcal{O}_{x_0}(V_\mathbb{C}(R))$ because of the smoothness hypothesis of $R$ at $x_0$. It implies that $R|S$ hence $V_\mathbb{C}(R) \subset V_\mathbb{C}(S)$ and it proves that $V_\mathbb{C}(R) = \overline{V_\mathbb{R}(R)}$.

Notice that for all $x$,
$$
\nabla P(x) = \begin{pmatrix} 10x_1 + 6x_2 + 4x_3 + 4 \\ 6x_1 + 6x_2 \\ 4x_1 + 4 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad \nabla Q_t(x) = \begin{pmatrix} -2x_1 \\ 2x_2 -4 \\ (2t + 4)x_3 \end{pmatrix},
$$
so both $P$ and $Q_t$ verify the hypothesis of the lemma with for example $x_0 = (0,0,-2)$ for $P$ and $x_0 = (\sqrt{2},0,0)$ for $Q_t$. Notice that it implies that both $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_{2,t}$ are indeed surfaces. If you take $R(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2$, its real zero locus is only a point, and the complexification would fail.

Now, if the affine transformation $f$ exists, $V_\mathbb{R}(P) = V_\mathbb{R}(Q_t \circ f)$ hence by the lemma ($Q_t \circ f$ also verifies the hypothesis of the lemma with $x_0 = f^{-1}(\sqrt{2},0,0)$ for example), $V_\mathbb{C}(P) = V_\mathbb{C}(Q_t \circ f)$. I let you check that $\nabla P$ doesn't vanishes on $V_\mathbb{C}(P)$, which implies that $P$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}$ so $I(V_\mathbb{C}(P)) = (P)$ by Hilbert's Nullstelensatz and with the same argument for $Q_t \circ f$, $I(V_\mathbb{C}(Q_t \circ f)) = (Q_t \circ f)$. Therefore, the above equality implies the existence of a non zero constant $\alpha$ such that $P = \alpha Q_t \circ f$ and this constant has to be real because $P$ and $Q_t \circ f$ are real and non zero.

From now, you can always solve the equation $P = \alpha Q_t \circ f$ of unknowns the coefficients of $A$ and $b$, and $\alpha$ in the finite dimensional vector space of real polynomial with $3$ unkowns and of degree at most $2$. However, you have $13$ unknowns so unless you have a formal calculus software, it will be very long. Let us see some tricks to reduce the number of unknowns.

First of all $P = \alpha Q_t \circ f$ implies that each fiber of $P$ is affinely equivalent to a fiber of $Q_t$ (not only the zero locus). It also implies that singular points of $P$ are sent on signular points of $Q_t \circ f$. Indeed, $P = \alpha Q_t \circ f$ thus $dP = \alpha(dQ_t \circ f)df = \alpha(dQ_t \circ f)A$ and,
$$
dP(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 10x_1 + 6x_2 + 4x_3 + 4 \\ 6x_1 + 6x_2 \\ 4x_1 + 4 \end{pmatrix} = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = -\begin{pmatrix} 10 & 6 & 4 \\ 6 & 6 & 0 \\ 4 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 0 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
And,
$$
dQ_t(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} -2x_1 \\ 2x_2 -4 \\ (2t + 4)x_3 \end{pmatrix} = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \textrm{ or } x_1 = x_2 - 2 = 0 \textrm{ and } t = -2.
$$
We deduce that we must have $t \neq -2$ and $f(-1,1,0) = (0,2,0)$. It implies that $f$ can be written as $f(x) = A(x - (-1,1,0)) + (0,2,0)$ and evaluating $P = \alpha Q_t \circ f$ at $(-1,1,0)$, we obtain,
$$
P(-1,1,0) = 5 + 3 - 6 - 4 + 8 = 6 = \alpha Q_t(0,2,0) = \alpha(4 - 8 + 2) = -2\alpha.
$$
We deduce that $\alpha = -3$ necessarily. To conclude, we will use the second derivative. As $P$ and $-3Q_t \circ f$ both have degree $2$ their Hessian matrices are constants and,
$$
\nabla^2P = \begin{pmatrix} 10 & 6 & 4 \\ 6 & 6 & 0 \\ 4 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad \nabla^2(-3Q_t \circ f) = -3A^\top\nabla^2Q_tA = -3A^\top\begin{pmatrix} 
-2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2t + 4 \end{pmatrix}A.
$$
A matrix $A$ such that those equalities are verified exists if and only if $M = \begin{pmatrix} 10 & 6 & 4 \\ 6 & 6 & 0 \\ 4 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $N_t = -3\begin{pmatrix} 
-2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2t + 4 \end{pmatrix}$ are equivalent as quadratic forms i.e. if and only if they have the same signature. the signature of $M$ is $(2,1)$ and the signature of $N_t$ is $(1,2)$ if $t > -2$, $(1,1)$ if $t = -2$ and $(2,1)$ if $t < -2$. Therefore, we must have $t < -2$.

Reciprocally, if $t < -2$, such an $A$ exists (notice that it is not unique). Therefore, we have,
\begin{align*}
P(-1,1,0) & = -3Q_t(f(-1,1,0)) \textrm{ because this is how we chose $\alpha = -3$,}\\
\nabla P(-1,1,0) & = \nabla(-3Q_t \circ f)(-1,1,0)\ (= 0)\\
& \textrm{ because this is how be chose the value of $f$ at $(-1,1,0)$,}\\
\nabla^2P(-1,1,0) & = \nabla^2(-3Q_t \circ f)(-1,1,0) \textrm{ because this is how we chose $A$.}
\end{align*}
These three equalities, together with the fact that both $P$ and $-3Q_t \circ f$ have degree at most $2$, implies that $P = -3Q_t \circ f$, which is the wanted result. In conclusion, $\Pi_1 \cong \Pi_{2,t}$ if and only if $t < -2$.

I hope it makes things clearer. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a quicker way to do it. In general, when $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials of degree at most two, you can write,
$$
P(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^\top P_2x + p_1^\top x + p_0, \qquad Q(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^\top Q_2x + q_1^{\top} x + q_0,
$$
whith $P_2$ and $Q_2$ symmetric. To know if you can write $P(x) = \alpha Q(Ax + b)$, find $x_0$ and $x_1$ such that $P_2x_0 = p_1$ and $Q_2x_1 = p_2$, which are unique as long as $P_2$ and $Q_2$ are invertible (assume it is the case). Thn you must have $f(x_0) = x_1$ by the same argument as previously. Deduce the value of $\alpha$ by evaluating the above equality at $x_0$ and conclude by comparing the signatures of $P_2$ and $\alpha Q_2$. $f$ exists if and only if they are equal.